# getListView() not working showing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a `ListFragment` `OnItemClick` is not working; it's basically not getting called. I have been unable to find any errors in my code. Is this somehow a problem with `getListView`?

I've explored Google and StackOverflow but did not find a solution. Here's my code:

```
public class FragmentSongs extends ListFragment implements OnFragmentCreatedListener,OnItemClickListener {
    static ListView lv;
    private static final String TAG = FragmentSongs.class.getSimpleName();
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver1; 
    Vector<ForPLaylist> gtuMcaBean= new Vector<ForPLaylist>();
    Forplaylistadapter adaptor;
        String artist="";
        static int i=0,f=0,k=0;; 


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                trial t=new trial();
                t.onCreate();
                ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist, container,false);

                 metaRetriver1 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                lv=(ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                //data calculation here
                lv.setAdapter(adaptor);     
           //  lv = getListView();//showing error here if i call it
             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        int songIndex=position;
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra("songIndex",songIndex);
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);     

                        closefragment();
                        }


                        });
        return root;
            }
            OnFragmentCreatedListener listener;
            private void closefragment() {
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<String> msg) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                int songIndex=position;
                Intent in = new Intent(null, AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("songIndex",songIndex);
                startActivityForResult( in,100);     

            finish();

            }
            private void finish() {

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
                if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saved variable number: " + savedInstanceState.getInt("number"));
                }

                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
              //  lv=getListView();
            }
            @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            // lv = getListView();


            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try move your `getListView();`to `onActivityCreated` and make sure you call `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)` first

Comment: the thing u told is not showing any error but onsettemclick() is not working...........i mean the activity is not getting called

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the code in `onItemClick` of `ListFragment` **(not the code of `onItemClick` inside `onCreateView` method)**:

```
Intent in = new Intent(null, AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
```

Just change it to:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
```

Comment: it is already .....Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);

Comment: @developer No, as I said, the other `onItemClick` not the one inside `onCreateView`